# categories and sub-categories of posts are wrongly saved in DB

Tags: categories

I have a `jobs` category and under it I've created some sub-categories:
[image]

Now, when I create a post, sometimes, as seen below, the sub-category name comes before, and sometime after the category itself, no matter what I do and how i initially save the post, i can't make it so the the subcategory will always come before the category...

This is just killing me...

[image]

Comment: And why should it be different? Every post has set of categories (it's not ordered). You can make taxonomy remember the order in which terms are added to objects, but it's still not what you want to do. If you want to sort these categories by hierarchy, then, I'm afraid, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: in the post's loop I am doing '$category = get_the_category();' then `echo $category[0]->cat_name;` and it should give me the subcategory name, but if the Category name comes BEFORE the subcategory name, like the first screenshot example, then this doesn't work well...and I don't know what effects a post's order of these names..

Comment: I still can't understand, why do you assume, that categories will be sorted in any way - they won't, so you should not base on this assumption.

Comment: so how can I print a post's subcategory name in the page if I don't know how the data will look like when using `get_the_category()`...

Comment: You'll have to select all categories assigned to this post and sort them by hierarchy yourself.

Comment: it's very strange the system doesn't sort it by meaningful order, if there is an hierarchy involved.

Comment: Well, it's not. There is no such order defined. OK, you may think that your order is meaningful, but it's not a general case. Any other order could be meaningful too (alphabetical, chronological, and so forth).

Comment: yeah so at least wordpress would give the administrator the option to choose which order is meaningful to him, does it makes sense..?

Comment: Well... No, it doesn't. There is no point to implement such feature. Only small group of people would use it, and it will slow down every site... WordPress won't do everything for you, if you want some specific features. Don't be so lazy ;)

Comment: it wouldn't slow down, because it saves the categories in MySQL only once, and I need it to be saved in a specific order. I thing the best is to change it in the DB itself once for every post, so all will be like "development, jobs" and not the other way around.

Comment: You can do it however you want to, but you'll have to implement it yourself. And, please, DO NOT modify WordPress core db tables - you'll encounter much more serious problems then.